# Fold on non-lists?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In a recent assignment I have been asked to define fold functions for some non-list types. I'm still not quite able to wrap my head around this concept yet. Thus far, I have understood `fold` as performing over subsequent elements in the `list`. `fold` on `Tree` still do make intuitive sense, since one is able to apply some function recursively over the root's sub-trees.

However, on a datatype like:

```
Maybe a :: Nothing | Just a
```

There is no `list` (as it seems to me) to perform the fold action on.

I'm sure I have some issue with understanding the basic concepts here, and I would greatly appreciate some clearing up.

Comment: A hint: in a way, `Maybe a` can be thought of as a list of either 0 or 1 elements, and `fold` *is* clearly defined over each of those things.

Comment: To make this more explicit, note that anything `Foldable` can be converted to a list; `toList <$> [Nothing, Just True] == [[], [True]]`

Comment: I wonder which kind of "fold" you are actually required to implement. In Haskell, we have the `Foldable` class whose `foldr` is equivalent to list-ifying the data type and then using `foldr` on the resulting list. In other contexts, "fold" is a term for an _eliminator_, as in `cata` from `recursion-schemes`. In my very first CS exam, I was asked to produce a "fold on binary trees" during an oral test, and that was meant to be something like `cata`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foldable` is a pretty confusing class, to be honest, because it doesn't have an awful lot of laws and it's quite possible to write quite a lot of different `Foldable` instances for almost any given type. Fortunately, it's possible to figure out what a `Foldable` instance should do in a purely mechanical way based on a [`Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) instance for the same type—if there is one.

We have

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
  traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

`Traversable` has several different laws, but it turns out the most important one is `traverse Identity = Identity`. Let's see how this applies to `Maybe`:

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> Maybe a -> f (Maybe b)
traverse g Nothing = _none
traverse g (Just a) = _some
```

Now in the first case, you need to produce `f (Maybe b)`, and all you have is `g :: a -> f b`. Since you don't have any `f` values, and you don't have any `a` values, the only thing you can produce is `pure Nothing`.

In the second case, you have to produce `f (Maybe b)` and you have `g :: a -> f b` and `a`. So the only interesting way to start is to apply `g` to `a`, getting `g a :: f b`. Now you have two options to consider: you could throw away this value, and just return `Nothing`, or you can wrap it up in `Just`.

By the identity law, `traverse Identity (Just a) = Identity (Just a)`. So you're not allowed to return `Nothing`. The *only* legal definition is

```
traverse _ Nothing = pure Nothing
traverse g (Just a) = Just <$> g a
```

The `Traversable` instance for `Maybe` is completely determined by the `Traversable` laws and parametricity.

Now it's possible to fold using `traverse`:

```
foldMapDefault :: (Traversable t, Monoid m)
               => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldMapDefault f xs =
  getConst (traverse (Const . f) xs)
```

As this applies to `Maybe`,

```
foldMapDefault f Nothing =
  getConst (traverse (Const . f) Nothing)
foldMapDefault f (Just a) =
  getConst (traverse (Const . f) (Just a))
```

Expanding our definitions,

```
foldMapDefault f Nothing = getConst (pure Nothing)
foldMapDefault f (Just a) = getConst (Just <$> (Const (f a)))
```

By the definitions of `pure` and `<$>` for `Const`, these are

```
foldMapDefault f Nothing = getConst (Const mempty)
foldMapDefault f (Just a) = getConst (Const (f a))
```

Unwrapping the constructor,

```
foldMapDefault f Nothing = mempty
foldMapDefault f (Just a) = f a
```

And this is indeed exactly how `foldMap` is defined for `Maybe`.

Comment: This seems maybe a bit high level for the OP.   It's a good answer anyway, just some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

As "basic concepts" go, this is pretty mind-bending, so don't feel too bad.

It may help to set aside your intuition about what a fold does to a list and think about what *type* a specific folding function (let's use `foldr`) should have if applied to a `Maybe`.  Writing `List a` in place of `[a]` to make it clearer, the standard `foldr` on a list has type:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
```

Obviously, the corresponding fold on a Maybe must have type:

```
foldrMaybe :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Maybe a -> b
```

Think about what definition this could possibly have, given that it must be defined for all `a` and `b` without knowing anything else about the types.  As a further hint, see if there's a function already defined in `Data.Maybe` that has a similar type -- maybe (ha ha) that'll give you some ideas.

Comment: I think it is far from obvious that `foldMaybe` should have this type - I would say that `b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` is more 'obvious', as the type of `foldList` corresponds (almost) to the natural eliminator for lists, and `b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` is the natural eliminator for `Maybe` - indeed there is a function of this type in `Data.Maybe` (`maybe`). There is no `foldMaybe` with that type, excluding `Data.Foldable.foldr`, which has a much more general type (and the type of this function has little to do with `Maybe`, or even `List`)

Comment: Good point, but to clarify, I meant that it was obvious that `foldr` should have that type for Maybes by an obvious parallel with its type for Lists, not necessarily that the most natural fold for a Maybe should look like `foldr`.  I've edited the answer to make that clearer.  In fact, `Data.Foldable.foldr` is `Prelude.foldr` in current versions of Haskell, and its type does specialize to Lists and Maybes in this manner, even if `foldr` isn't the "natural" fold for a Maybe.